# Is there an OCR-Phonegap plugin?

Tags: ios, ocr, phonegap-plugins

I am building an app for the ipad using gwt-phonegap (as i dont know much about objective c and have no intentions of learning it).

I am stuck with a problem where i need to use OCR to parse a captured image and then show the result to the user.

Has anyone come across a phonegap plugin that i can use or can anyone suggest me a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can look for this plugin at the repository updated for the 2.0 version:

https://github.com/jcesarmobile/PhonegapOCRPlugin

Comment: The version you linked doesn't work with phonegap 2.0 and 2.1 because they haven't updated the repository with my pull request yet. The proper version is the one on my answer. Please, don't spread that link because people download it and then mail me because it doesn't work on 2.0 and 2.1

Answer (score 1):

I created this OCR plugin

http://goo.gl/9To23

it uses the tessearc OCR library.

I have tested it with phonegap 1.8 and 1.9

EDIT:
Just updated the repository, now included the latest version of tesseract and now it works with phonegap 2.0.0 and 2.1 RC2 (I think, I have only tested with 2.1 RC2, but I solved a duplicate main symbol)